# Illogical TF Chain

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Gazebo (Simulated PR2 in Groovy), with /fake_localization, /robot_pose_ekf and /robot_state_publisher.

Something seems to be off with my /tf tree.

$ rosrun tf tf_monitor /map /base_laser_link
Waiting for transform chain to become available between /map and /base_laser_link

```
RESULTS: for /map to /base_laser_link
Chain is: /bl_caster_rotation_link -> /base_link -> /bl_caster_rotation_link -> /base_footprint -> /br_caster_rotation_link -> /base_link -> /br_caster_rotation_link -> /fl_caster_rotation_link -> /base_link -> /fl_caster_rotation_link -> /fr_caster_rotation_link -> /base_link -> /fr_caster_rotation_link -> /torso_lift_link -> /base_link -> /head_pan_link -> /torso_lift_link -> /base_link -> /base_link -> /odom_combined -> /base_link -> /head_tilt_link -> /torso_lift_link -> /torso_lift_link -> /laser_tilt_mount_link -> /torso_lift_link -> /map -> NO_PARENT
Net delay     avg = 0.00779586: max = 0.066

Frames:
Frame: /base_footprint published by /robot_pose_ekf Average Delay: 0.0243333 Max Delay: 0.035
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /base_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.48425 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /bl_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /bl_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /br_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /br_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /fl_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /fl_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /fr_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /fr_caster_rotation_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /head_pan_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /head_tilt_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /laser_tilt_mount_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /odom_combined published by /fake_localization Average Delay: -0.0568421 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /torso_lift_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /torso_lift_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /torso_lift_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /torso_lift_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064
Frame: /torso_lift_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.038 Max Delay: 0.064

All Broadcasters:
Node: /fake_localization 111.111 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0568421 Max Delay: 0
Node: /robot_pose_ekf 35.7143 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0243333 Max Delay: 0.035
Node: /robot_state_publisher 107.843 Hz, Average Delay: -0.246864 Max Delay: 0.064
```

Why would TF do such a horrible thing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73219/illogical-tf-chain/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-14**:
@David Lu please don't use # in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bug in the chainAsVector output only(which is used by monitor.  It's ticketed here: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/22

There was a placeholder algorithm which was put in when the change in data storage was made, but the placeholder was never removed.  It's currently iterating all frames and printing their parents.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1